# AuthenticatedRouteMixin: No redirection when route hooks are overridden

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

Authentication seems to be skipped if I define beforeModel hook in my index route.
Maybe this overrides the mixin's beforeModel...

Example: the following does not redirect me to /login until I remove 'beforeModel' from my route.
The same for 'afterModel' and possibly other hooks

```
// app/routes/index.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin,{
 beforeModel : function(){
    // empty function
  }
});
```

any help would be appreciated.
What I want to do is simple transitions from route to route. Eg. go to /users/userlist when the URL is simple /users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This overrides the mixin's implementation as you already suggested. You need to call `this._super(transition);`:

```
beforeModel: function(transition, queryParams) {
  this._super(transition, queryParams);
  …
}
```

Comment: tried this. it gives me the following error in the console: Cannot read property 'abort' of undefined TypeError:Cannot read property 'abort' of undefined

Comment: Let me note that I don't get this error if the route does not make use of the mixin. So, when the mixin is used at the route, a call to this._super(); throws an error in the console.

Comment: you need to pass the transition param - fixed the answer above